# Shorter way to disable multiple forms with different ID

Tags: javascript

I'm new to web development. I'm using `document.getElementById("id").disabled=true;`to disable a form. But I have multiple forms. As shown in the code below for example, I repeated the the same function three times. How do we write this code in a shorter way? It must be pure javascript.

```js
function readOnly(){
        document.getElementById("firstname").disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("lastname").disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("email").disabled=true;
      }
```

Comment: for(let tL=document.querySelectorAll('#firstname, #lastname, #email'), i=0, j=tL.length; i<j; i++) tL[i].disabled = true

Comment: You can use classes for your form elements and `let MyClassList = document.getElementsByClassName("MyClass");` will let you the possibility to loop the elements to disable.